# AttributeError: 'DistilBertConfig' object has no attribute 'return_dict'

Tags: python, pipeline, attributeerror, huggingface-transformers

I am getting the AttributeError on this statement:

```
prediction = cdqa_pipeline.predict(query, 3).
```

I am using CDQA Pipelining. cdqa==1.3.7 and transformers==4.6.1

I am also using the distilbert-squad_1.1

Here is the trace:

```
query = 'What are the gas bubbles in basalt called?'
prediction = cdqa_pipeline.predict(query, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f1b43e857cff> in <module>
      1 query = 'What are the gas bubbles in basalt called?'
----> 2 prediction = cdqa_pipeline.predict(query, 1)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cdqa\pipeline\cdqa_sklearn.py in predict(self, query, n_predictions, retriever_score_weight, return_all_preds)
    187             n_predictions=n_predictions,
    188             retriever_score_weight=retriever_score_weight,
--> 189             return_all_preds=return_all_preds,
    190         )
    191         return prediction

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cdqa\reader\bertqa_sklearn.py in predict(self, X, n_predictions, retriever_score_weight, return_all_preds)
   1468                     inputs['token_type_ids'] = batch[2]
   1469                 example_indices = batch[3]
-> 1470                 batch_start_logits, batch_end_logits = self.model(**inputs)
   1471 
   1472             for i, example_index in enumerate(example_indices):

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    530             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    531         else:
--> 532             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    533         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    534             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_distilbert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, head_mask, inputs_embeds, start_positions, end_positions, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    706             sequence are not taken into account for computing the loss.
    707         """
--> 708         return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
    709 
    710         distilbert_output = self.distilbert(

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py in use_return_dict(self)
    250         """
    251         # If torchscript is set, force `return_dict=False` to avoid jit errors
--> 252         return self.return_dict and not self.torchscript
    253 
    254     @property

AttributeError: 'DistilBertConfig' object has no attribute 'return_dict'
```

Comment: Please show us how you have initialized your pipeline and other variables.

Comment: This is the cell where I define and invoke the pipline:

Comment: `cdqa_pipeline = QAPipeline(reader='./models/distilbert_qa.joblib', max_df=1.0)
cdqa_pipeline.fit_retriever(df=df)`

Comment: 'cdqa_pipeline = QAPipeline(reader='./models/distilbert_qa.joblib', max_df=1.0)`

`cdqa_pipeline.fit_retriever(df=df)'

Comment: Ignore my first messy response.  I guess StackOverlow comments do not support new lines.   The Jupyter cell has two separate lines.
The next cell looks like this:
`query = 'What are the gas bubbles in basalt called?'`
`prediction = cdqa_pipeline.predict(query, 1)`

Comment: What is `./models/distilbert_qa.joblib`? Is that a pytorch state_dict?

Comment: My question exactly.  I had never heard a model be referred to as a *.joblib.  It's a "SciKit" thing.  From what I can make out, it's some kid of bundle.  It bundles up the model and its weights and associate Python objects.

Comment: It appeared in the models directory of my notebook after executing the cell
` download_model(model='distilbert-squad_1.1', dir='./models')`

Comment: Your question was an excellent one.  It got me to thinking that maybe I shoud be searching the web for "sklearn + AttributeError: 'DistilBertConfig' object has no attribute 'return_dict'". 

I found this right here on StackOverflow: "can't use scikit-learn - "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute ..." which just might have a solution to my issue.